# LoadLibrary on boost thread

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, load

I have some problem with load DLL on win32. I have boost thread and I try to load DLL:

```
HINSTANCE DllPtr; DllPtr = LoadLibrary("path_to_dll");

if (DllPtr == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "Load library failed because of " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

and output of GetLastError is

> 998 ERROR_NOACCESS.

I have no idea what is the problem, because the path to dll is correct.

Comment: The entrypoint of the DLL, DllMain(), crashed and burned with an access violation.  That doesn't have anything to do with the path to the DLL of course.  Heap corruption is the usual cause.

Comment: Could you tell me something more about what could cause Heap corruption ?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388.aspx#ERROR_NOACCESS): *Invalid access to memory location.* Always a good idea to consult the documentation. Clearly there's a problem with the DLL. You'll need to do some debugging.

Comment: I have no idea what was the main problem, but i clean and rebuild project and it works :) Hans and David thank you for help.